# How to join two DataFrames and change column for missing values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("a1",10,"ACTIVE","ds1"),
   ("a1",20,"ACTIVE","ds1"),
   ("a2",50,"ACTIVE","ds1"),
   ("a3",60,"ACTIVE","ds1"))
).toDF("c1","c2","c3","c4")`

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("a1",10,"ACTIVE","ds2"),
   ("a1",20,"ACTIVE","ds2"),
   ("a1",30,"ACTIVE","ds2"),
   ("a1",40,"ACTIVE","ds2"),
   ("a4",20,"ACTIVE","ds2"))
).toDF("c1","c2","c3","c5")`


df1.show()

// +---+---+------+---+
// | c1| c2|    c3| c4|
// +---+---+------+---+
// | a1| 10|ACTIVE|ds1|
// | a1| 20|ACTIVE|ds1|
// | a2| 50|ACTIVE|ds1|
// | a3| 60|ACTIVE|ds1|
// +---+---+------+---+

df2.show()
// +---+---+------+---+
// | c1| c2|    c3| c5|
// +---+---+------+---+
// | a1| 10|ACTIVE|ds2|
// | a1| 20|ACTIVE|ds2|
// | a1| 30|ACTIVE|ds2|
// | a1| 40|ACTIVE|ds2|
// | a4| 20|ACTIVE|ds2|
// +---+---+------+---+
```

My requirement is: I need to Join both dataframes.
My output dataframe should be having all the records from df1 and also the records from df2 which are not in df1 for the matching "c1" only. And the records which I pull from df2 should be updated to Inactive at column "c3".

In this example only matching value of "c1" is a1. So I need to pull c2=30 and 40 records from df2 and make them INACTIVE.

Here is the output.

```
df_output.show()

// +---+---+--------+---+
// | c1| c2|    c3  | c4|
// +---+---+--------+---+
// | a1| 10|ACTIVE  |ds1|
// | a1| 20|ACTIVE  |ds1|
// | a2| 50|ACTIVE  |ds1|
// | a3| 60|ACTIVE  |ds1|
// | a1| 30|INACTIVE|ds1|
// | a1| 40|INACTIVE|ds1|
// +---+---+--------+---+
```

Can any one help me to do this.

Comment: Does the c4 value changes from ds2 to ds1 for INACTIVE records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a small thing. I use different names for the columns in `df2`:

```
val df2 = sc.parallelize(...).toDF("d1","d2","d3","d4")
```

No big deal, but this made things easier for me to reason about.

Now for the fun stuff. I am going to be a bit verbose for the sake of clarity:

```
val join = df1
.join(df2, df1("c1") === df2("d1"), "inner")
.select($"d1", $"d2", $"d3", lit("ds1").as("d4"))
.dropDuplicates
```

Here I do the following:

- Inner join between `df1` and `df2` on the `c1` and `d1` columns
- Select the `df2` columns and simply "hardcode" `ds1` in the last column to replace `ds2`
- Drop duplicates

This basically just filters out everything in `df2` that *does not* have a corresponding key in `c1` in `df1`.

Next I diff:

```
val diff = join
.except(df1)
.select($"d1", $"d2", lit("INACTIVE").as("d3"), $"d4")
```

This is a basic set operation that finds everything in `join` that is *not* in `df1`. These are the items to deactivate, so I select all the columns but replace the third with a hardcoded `INACTIVE` value.

All that's left is to put them all together:

```
df1.union(diff)
```

This simply combines `df1` with the table of deactivated values we calculated earlier to produce the final result:

```
+---+---+--------+---+
| c1| c2|      c3| c4|
+---+---+--------+---+
| a1| 10|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 20|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a2| 50|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a3| 60|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 30|INACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 40|INACTIVE|ds1|
+---+---+--------+---+
```

And again, you don't need all these intermediate values. I just was verbose to help trace through the process.

Comment: `val c1Ids = df1.select("c1").as[String].collect()`
`val joinDf = df1.as("t1").join(df2.as("t2"), df1("c1") === df2("c1"), "rightouter").select($"t2.c1", $"t2.c2").distinct().withColumn("c3", lit("INACTIVE")).withColumn("c4",lit("ds1")).filter(not($"c1").isin(c1Ids: _*))`

Comment: `val finalDf = df1.unionAll(joinDf)`   This should give the output.

Comment: I'm sure there are multiple ways--perhaps some better than mine--to get that output. Glad to point you in the right direction. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

here is dirty solution -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


# find the rows from df2 that have matching key c1 in df2
df3 = df1.join(df2,df1.c1==df2.c1)\
.select(df2.c1,df2.c2,df2.c3,df2.c5.alias('c4'))\
.dropDuplicates()

df3.show()
```

:

```
+---+---+------+---+
| c1| c2|    c3| c4|
+---+---+------+---+
| a1| 10|ACTIVE|ds2|
| a1| 20|ACTIVE|ds2|
| a1| 30|ACTIVE|ds2|
| a1| 40|ACTIVE|ds2|
+---+---+------+---+
```

:

```
# Union df3 with df1 and change columns c3 and c4 if c4 value is 'ds2'

df1.union(df3).dropDuplicates(['c1','c2'])\
.select('c1','c2',\
        F.when(df1.c4=='ds2','INACTIVE').otherwise('ACTIVE').alias('c3'),
        F.when(df1.c4=='ds2','ds1').otherwise('ds1').alias('c4')
       )\
.orderBy('c1','c2')\
.show()
```

:

```
+---+---+--------+---+
| c1| c2|      c3| c4|
+---+---+--------+---+
| a1| 10|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 20|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 30|INACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 40|INACTIVE|ds1|
| a2| 50|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a3| 60|  ACTIVE|ds1|
+---+---+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Enjoyed the challenge and here is my solution.

```
val c1keys = df1.select("c1").distinct
val df2_in_df1 = df2.join(c1keys, Seq("c1"), "inner")
val df2inactive = df2_in_df1.join(df1, Seq("c1", "c2"), "leftanti").withColumn("c3", lit("INACTIVE"))
scala> df1.union(df2inactive).show
+---+---+--------+---+
| c1| c2|      c3| c4|
+---+---+--------+---+
| a1| 10|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 20|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a2| 50|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a3| 60|  ACTIVE|ds1|
| a1| 30|INACTIVE|ds2|
| a1| 40|INACTIVE|ds2|
+---+---+--------+---+
```